# Cómo exportar a Excel una consulta de búsqueda (Filtro) - Maatwebsite y Laravel

Tags: laravel

Tengo un buscador en Laravel y me funciona bien. Y también puedo descargar mi listado completo en Excel utilizando Maatwebsite, lo que requiero es poder descargar en el excel el filtro (resultados) de la búqueda.

No sé como hacerlo, estoy buscando en google pero no doy.

Este es mi archivo Export

```
<?php

namespace App\Exports;

use App\Visit;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;

class VisitsExport implements FromCollection, WithHeadings
{
/**
* @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
*/
public function collection()
{
    return Visit::all();
}

public function headings(): array
{
    return [
        'Id',
        'Código',
        'Id Empresa',
        'Nombre',
        'Apellido',
        'Teléfono',
        'DNI',
        'Mesa',
        'Aplicante',
        'Acepto?',
        'Tiempo',
        'Fecha',
    ];
}
}
```

En mi Controlador:

```
public function search(Request $request)
{

    $visits = Visit::leftjoin('users', 'visits.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
                    ->search($request->visits)
                    ->paginate(12);

    return view('admin.dashboard.visits.admin-index', compact('visits'));

}
```

En mi Scope tengo lo siguiente:

```
public function scopeSearch($query, $find)
{
    $search = explode(" ", $find);
    $total = count($search);

    $array = array();
    for($i=0; $i<$total; $i++ ) {
         if( $i == 0 ) {
              $array = $query->where(DB::raw("CONCAT(code, ' ', name, ' ', u_last_name, ' ', dni, ' ', v_first_name, ' ', v_last_name, ' ', v_phone)"), "LIKE", "%".Stemm_es::stemm($search[$i])."%");
          } else {
              $array = $array->orWhere(DB::raw("CONCAT(code, ' ', name, ' ', u_phone, ' ', dni, ' ', v_first_name, ' ', v_last_name, ' ', v_phone)"), "LIKE", "%".Stemm_es::stemm($search[$i])."%");
          }
    }
    return $array;
}
```

Quedo atento a cualquier ayuda, de antemano muchas gracias

Llamado:

```
public function excel()
{
    return Excel::download(new VisitsExport, 'products.xlsx');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La forma en la que exportas el excel parece ser muy sencilla y rápida, pero no veo desde donde haces la llamada a la clase `VisitsExport`, me atrevería a decir que al momento de llamar a dicha clase o una función de esta debes de enviar el `request`, mas o menos asi:

```
public function collection(Request $request)
{
    return Visit::leftjoin('users', 'visits.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
                    ->search($request->visits)
                    ->get();
}
```

Ten en cuenta que no se como creaste tus clases ni como las estas llamando, Asi que es posible que no te sirva.

Por otra parte te dejare un trozo de código de como me gusta exportar un excel:

La siguiente funcion puede estar dentro de un controlador y llamarlo como a cualquier otra función desde las rutas de laravel:

```
public function aguinaldoviewexcel(Request $request){ 
    /*inicio de obtencion de datos*/
    $empresa=$request->empresa; 
    $socio=$request->socio;
    $detalle=$request->detalle;
    $start=$request->start;
    $end=$request->end;
    $lista=null;


    $name_empresa="";
    $name_socio="";
    
    if($empresa!='CONSOLIDADO'){
        $em=\App\Models\Control\Sitio::find(hashid_decode($empresa));
        $name_empresa=$em->nombre;
    }else{
        $name_empresa=$empresa;
    }
    if($socio!='CONSOLIDADO'){
        $em=\App\Models\Core\Socio::find(hashid_decode($socio));
        $name_socio=$em->razon_social;
    }else{
        $name_socio=$socio;
    }

    switch ($detalle) {
        case 'empresa':
            if($request->empresa!='CONSOLIDADO'){
                $datos=\App\Models\Control\Sitio::with('planillas')->where('id',hashid_decode($request->empresa))->get();
                
                $cadena='<div style="color:#000">Aguinaldos<br>'.$datos[0]->nombre.' <br> Desde: '.$start.' Hasta '.$end."<br></div>";
            }else{
                $datos=\App\Models\Control\Sitio::with('planillas')->get();
                $cadena='<div style="color:#000">Aguinaldos<br>CONSOLIDADO <br> Desde: '.$start.' Hasta '.$end."<br></div>";
            }
            $lista= $this->empresaList($datos,$empresa,$socio,$start,$end,$cadena);
            break;
        case 'socio':
            if($request->socio!='CONSOLIDADO'){
                $datos=\App\Models\Core\Socio::with('planillas')->where('id',hashid_decode($request->socio))->get();
                $cadena='<div style="color:#000">Aguinaldos<br>'.$datos[0]->razon_social.' <br> Desde: '.$start.' Hasta '.$end."<br></div>";
            }else{
                $datos=\App\Models\Core\Socio::with('planillas')->get();
                $cadena='<div style="color:#000">Aguinaldos<br>CONSOLIDADO <br> Desde: '.$start.' Hasta '.$end."<br></div>";
            }
            $lista= $this->socioList($datos,$empresa,$socio,$start,$end,$cadena);
            
    }
    /*fin de obtención de datos, hasta aqui podrías hacer tus consultas*/
    /*inicio de creacion del excel*/
    Excel::create('AGUINALDOS DE LA COOPERATIVA XYZ R.L.', function($excel) use($lista,$name_empresa,$start,$end){
        $excel->sheet('Sheetname', function($sheet) use($lista,$name_empresa,$start,$end){
            /*Inicio de cabecera del excel*/
            $sheet->mergeCells('A1:D1');
            $sheet->row(1, function ($row) {$row->setAlignment('center');});
            $sheet->row(1, array($name_empresa.'','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','',''));
            $sheet->mergeCells('A2:D2');
            $sheet->row(2, function ($row) {$row->setAlignment('center');});
            $sheet->row(2, array('POTOSÍ - BOLIVIA','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','',''));
            $sheet->mergeCells('A3:S3');
            $sheet->row(3, function ($row) {$row->setAlignment('center');$row->setFontWeight('bold');});
            $sheet->row(3, array('DETALLE DE APORTES A LA COOPERATIVA XYZ R.L.','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','',''));
            $sheet->mergeCells('A4:S4');
            $sheet->row(4, function ($row) {$row->setAlignment('center');$row->setFontWeight('bold');});
            $sheet->row(4, array(date_mes_string($start).' a '.date_mes_string($end).'','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','',''));
            $sheet->row(6, function ($row) {$row->setAlignment('center');$row->setFontWeight('bold');$row->setBackground('#000000');$row->setFontColor('#ffffff');});
            //la siguiente linea es similar a tu funcion headings
            $sheet->row(6, array("Nro","Fecha","Socio","N. Lote","Peso Bruto","Ley Zinc","Ley Plata","Ley Plomo","Importe Bruto","5%","2%","7%"));
            /*Fin de cabecera del excel*/
            $rowss = 7;
            /*Inicio de listado de valores*/
            foreach ($lista as $dat){

                $sheet->row($rowss,$dat);
                $rowss++;
            }
            /*fin de listado de valores*/
            $sheet->mergeCells('A'.$rowss.':D'.$rowss);
            $sheet->mergeCells('F'.$rowss.':H'.$rowss);
            $sheet->row($rowss, function ($row) {$row->setFontWeight('bold');$row->setBackground('#dddddd');});
            
            $rowss+=3;
            $sheet->mergeCells('A'.$rowss.':E'.$rowss);
            $sheet->mergeCells('F'.$rowss.':M'.$rowss);
            $sheet->mergeCells('N'.$rowss.':S'.$rowss);
            $sheet->row($rowss, function ($row) {$row->setAlignment('center');});
            $sheet->row($rowss, array('ELABORADO POR','','','','','TESORERO','','','','','','','','PRESIDENTE ADM.','','','','',''));
            $rowss++;
            $sheet->mergeCells('A'.$rowss.':E'.$rowss);
            $sheet->mergeCells('F'.$rowss.':M'.$rowss);
            $sheet->mergeCells('N'.$rowss.':S'.$rowss);
            $sheet->row($rowss, function ($row) {$row->setAlignment('center');});
            $sheet->row($rowss, array('','','','','','Verificado por','','','','','','','','Aprobado por','','','','',''));
        });
    })->export('xlsx');
    /*fin de creacion del excel*/
}
```

Puedes leer los comentarios para entenderlo a grandes rasgos.
Ahora pasare a explicarlo lo mas detallado posible y tratando de adaptarlo a tu codigo:

Donde el primer comentario **obtención de datos** puedes realizar tu consulta.

```
$visits = Visit::leftjoin('users', 'visits.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
                ->search($request->visits)
                ->get();
```

Luego le pasas los valores a la funcion `Excel::create`:

```
Excel::create('Nombre del documento', function($excel) use ($visits){
```

También debes de pasarlo a la hoja en la que quieres utilizarla:

```
 $excel->sheet('nombre de la hoja', function($sheet) use($visit){
```

De ahi en adelante existen funciones para adornar nuestro documento:

```
             Funcion                             |          lo que realiza                  

$sheet->row($fila, function ($row) {...});       |Se utiliza para aplicar estilos a la $fila N
$sheet->row($fila, array("valor1","valor2",...));|Agrega una nueva fila con los valores del array
$sheet->mergeCells('A1:D1');                     |Combina las celdas desde A1 hasta D1
$row->setAlignment('center')                     |Centra el texto
$row->setFontWeight('bold')                      |Cambia el texto a bold
$row->setBackground('#000000');                  |Cambia el color de fondo
$row->setFontColor('#ffffff');                   |Cambia el color de texto
```

Puedes ver mas funciones en su documentación oficial https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/getting-started/

Pero la parte mas importante debería de ser el **Listado de valores**

```
$rowss = 7; // fila desde donde inicia el listado
foreach ($visits as $v){
   $sheet->row($rowss,[$v->id,$v->codigo,$v->empresa_id,$v->nombre,$v->apellido,$v->apellido,$v->telefono,$v->dni,$v->mesa,$v->aplicante,"acepto?",$v->tiempo,$fecha]);
   $rowss++;
}
```

Oh!!!, pero que rollo, es mucho código para tan simple cosas!!!.

Joder, las mejores cosas tienen un costo mas alto.

Pero si lo quieres hacer a tu modo puedes leer https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/from-query.html

Espero que todo lo que explique se haya entendido y que te sirva.

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder... Agregué el llamado en la pregunta. Ya leo tu respuesta.

Comment: Sigo intentando, de varias maneras pero no lo consigo aún. Te mantengo al tanto

Comment: Gracias, siempre dispuesto a ayudar. "Joder, las mejores cosas tienen un costo mas alto." Cierto!